# How to create dateTime in flutter which should not affect by dayLight Saving

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) timezone for converting local DateTime to timeZone specific.

I am in India I want to set time based on other countries timezone which should not change on if I am changing the timezone of my phone or beacuse of dayLight saving it should not get affected

```
try {


  DateTime dt = DateFormat(format).parse(date);

  String timeZOne = sharedPreference.getString(Constants.PREF_TIMEZONE);
  String offset = tz.getLocation(timeZOne).currentTimeZone.offset.toString();
  var local = TZDateTime.local(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second);



  DateTime afterAdd;
  if (offset.contains("-")) {
    afterAdd = local.add(Duration(milliseconds: int.tryParse(offset.toString()).abs()));
  } else {
    afterAdd = local.subtract(Duration(milliseconds: int.tryParse(offset.toString()).abs()));
  }

    timeZoneBasedMilliSeconds =TZDateTime.from(afterAdd,tz.getLocation(timeZOne)).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  

  return timeZoneBasedMilliSeconds;
  
} catch (e) {
  Utility.log(e);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you use all dates in UTC and only present the date you want in specific zone? I think when you use local time the daylight is affected and in UTC should not

Comment: I was able to solve this issue thanks for your response